# How can I announce a Class before it is declared?

Tags: c++, class, prototype

How can I announce a Class before it is declared?

I think I need something like a class prototype.

```
Class First
{
    public:
        int Method1(Second* second); // Error: Undefined class Second
    private:
        int Attribute1;
}
Class Second
{
    public:
        int Method1(First* first);
    private:
        int Attribute2;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to *declare* a class before it is *defined*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration):

```
class Second;
class First
{
    public:
        int Method1(Second* second);
    private:
        int Attribute1;
};
```

Comment: Just keep in mind: you also can do this with a reference of the class Second.